# gradle uses its own dependency instead of build.gradle for commons-cli

Tags: java, gradle

My project does not compile because I have configured my build.gradle to use commons-cli-1.3, while gradle uses commons-cli-1.2:

```
compile 'commons-cli:commons-cli:1.3'
```

If I do dependency insight properly shows what I expect:

```
commons-cli:commons-cli:1.3
\--- compile
```

However, if I inspect `configurations.compile.asPath` I will see lib/plugins/commons-cli-1.2.jar on the path before commons-cli-1.3.jar!

This appears to be because I have project dependency on a project that has compile dependency gradleApi() - which uses the 1.2.jar (not reported in dependencyInsight)

I see this happening in gradle 2.3 and 2.7, at least.

Anyone run into this and have a solution?
Seems like pretty junky and non-transparent behavior on gradle's part

Comment: https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1715

Answer (score 1):

So, here's what I did to solve it, in my case...
instead of using gradleApi() in my other project dependency, I added these explicitly:

```
compile 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.6'
compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.5'
```

Even if this didn't solve my issue (which it did), this does then make these dependencies more easy to see/manage e.g. adding {exclude:} clause, etc. I guess gradleApi() is just a terrible "convenience" feature (see long-standing bug: https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1715)